# A doubt regarding sum of Infinite G.P.

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

I've been taught that sum$(S)$ of first $n$ terms of G.P. is given by–
                 $$S=\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$$ where, $a$ is first term of G.P., $r$ is common ratio and $r>1$ or $r<-1$

But, if we talk about infinite G.P., the sum $(S)$ is given by–
                 $$S=\frac{a}{1-r}$$ where, $a$ is first term of G.P., $r$ is common ratio.
 But here, $|r|$$<$$1$.

And, the reason my teacher gave for the derivation of formula is that–
   as, $n$$\to$$\infty$, $r^n$$\to$$0$.

*Doubt*= Since $r^n$$≈$$0$ , So sum of infinite G.P. must also be an approximation.Isn't it????

Comment: It's not clear to me what your doubt it, specifically.

Comment: Is sum of  infinite G.P. an approximation???

Comment: No, it's exact.  The "sum" of an infinite series is a limit, not an actual "sum."

Comment: as you said the limit as $n\to\infty$ gives $r^n\to 0$ for $|r|<1$ rather than $r^n=0$. The sum does not equal this value, it just approaches it as $n\to\infty$

Comment: Since $r^n$ just tends to $0$, then why we put value of $r^n=0$ in formula of sum of $n$ terms to get the formula of infinite sum.

Comment: Can you guys make your sentence more clear, pls pls!! or any simpler explaination, cause I am not able to relate the terms "tend to " and "equal to".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion might be with what limits are. If I ask you, "as $x$ goes to $\infty$, what happens to the value of $\frac{1}{x}+5$," what would you say? Well, the expression $\frac{1}{x} + 5$ approaches -- but never actually reaches -- $5$. You can verify this: there is no single $x$ for which $1/x = 0$.

In a similar way, the value of an infinite geometric series can be seen as a limit, namely, $$S = \frac{a}{1-r} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i = 1}^n r^i.$$

There is no $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n r^i = S$. But as we keep on increasing the number of terms in the sum, we get closer and closer to $S = \frac{a}{1-r}$.